# Project bibtex works on Overleaf but not locally when using a template

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, overleaf

MRE:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/cftjknrfbcvt

On Overleaf the bibliography works:

[image]

Locally (I click download source, and I unzip) I get:

[image]

I have tried:

- Uninstalling and re-installing my LiveTex (I had version 2021, I tried version 2022 and now I'm using version 2023). More details on my current version (Windows 11):

```
TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Copyright 2023 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

- My bibtex version, I don't know if I can update it, I couldn't find much on the internet:

```
BibTeX 0.99d (TeX Live 2023)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Copyright 2023 Oren Patashnik.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the BibTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the BibTeX source.
Primary author of BibTeX: Oren Patashnik.
```

- I have tried using PdfLatex since that's what overleaf uses. It doesn't work. I tried all compilers I had, none worked correctly. Most straight up raised errors.
- I have tried restarting my computer, and repeated all steps above.
- I have tried using another IDE (I was using TexStudio, I tried TeXworks editor). No difference. Which I guess makes sense since they use the same compiler.

Comment: you probably need to run biber and not bibtex.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/2388 but be aware that I did not check your link as I don't debug external code.

Comment: Using pdfLatex then Biber then pdfLatex worked. Thanks @Ulrike Fischer

Comment: May I ask how did you know? @UlrikeFischer, I've read about the differences between the two but could I have guessed instead of just trying both?

Comment: you are not the first running bibtex instead of biber, with a bit experience it is easy to make such a guess--and I have quite a lot experience.

Comment: biblatex (biber) makes unknown cite have [key]  whereas with bibtex  you get [?] so your image was enough to guess